# Typescript, How to constrain types according to function parameters?

Tags: typescript

What can be done to make the useWatchProps callback function parameters correspond to the first parameter

```
type KeysToValues<O extends Record<string, any>, K> = K extends [
  infer G,
  ...infer L
]
  ? G extends keyof O
    ? [O[G], ...KeysToValues<O, L>]
    : []
  : []

function useWatchProps<
  O extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends keyof O = keyof O,
  T extends K | K[] = K | K[]
>(
  keys: T,
  callback: (values: T extends K ? O[K] : KeysToValues<O, K>) => void
) {}

useWatchProps<{ a: number; b: string }>('a', (a) => {
  a // number
})
useWatchProps<{ a: number; b: string }>(['a', 'b'], ([a, b]) => {
  a // number
  b // string
})
```

How to constrain T by keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not passing the `T`, it gets automatically turned to the default value that you have assigned. Unfortunately, we can't specify only the portion of the required parameters; thus, I can suggest making `useWatchProps` accept only `O` and return another function. Usage will look like this:

```
useWatchProps<{ a: number; b: string }>()('a', (a) => {
  a; // number
});
```

We will also need to change `T` to a [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to avoid compiler turning the `T` to a union. This will cause to turn all checks of the `T` to `readonly some_array/some_tuple`.

Modifications:

```
type KeysToValues<O extends Record<string, any>, K> = K extends readonly [
  infer G,
  ...infer L,
]
  ? G extends keyof O
    ? [O[G], ...KeysToValues<O, L>]
    : []
  : K
```

Implementation:

```
function useWatchProps<O extends Record<string, any>>() {
  return <const T extends keyof O | readonly (keyof O)[]>(
    keys: T,
    callback: (values: T extends keyof O ? O[T] : KeysToValues<O, T> ) => void,
  ) => {};
}
```

Usage:

```
useWatchProps<{ a: number; b: string }>()('a', (a) => {
  a; // number
});
useWatchProps<{ a: number; b: string }>()(['a', 'b'] , ([a,b]) => {
  a; // number
  b; // string
});
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcAqB7AagQwDYFcIIB4B5KCAD2AgDsATBKAJQgGMUAnGghYNgSyoDmAGigYqIAHwiYEqAF5YpCtTpQ2EDDRRUsIKAG0AUFCj8AZhDZQA4kONQAdE-OWoAGTsBdewH4bSylp6AGt4FDMoInsTP30ifWtPEScHOERUTFx8YhE3CW8TEwAuAwKoEphDQzMcKmZgXm0oHAQIAHUMYGYACwAFNhQwQhJyQNUmVg4uHn5hUXEJCQAKAEooAG97dWAcNiooAlYqbigkAJUQsIiSAB81DS0dPSXQkHDIlf1PZeioV4QSkg7IUoMxsFgAEYYZjBEpLABu2DwANO5yCfyukSgfniSE85Vg8GQ6CR2SIIiQsjWclk8JQvBowKg1Nk6wAvgBuQxsqotdqdHr9QaEdaiEpUHAAWwhlg5UAhJW4fEEUDZyxWSwA5BhNSIlhgWRt7Bg5QB6U1QCXSyzclZcvkdLp9AZDAiijDiqUythyhVQJWzVXqpb6bW6qCaiGa-F6-QYIQQzyGzYmE1Qc2Wr02kwQs0WgOCW1coA)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is the `<const T extends keyof O | readonly (keyof O)[]>` syntax released after 5.0 and is there a release document for it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was only able to find release notes, that I already included in the answer